# How to send multiple images in formdata format in Angular 4

Tags: angular, image, multipartform-data

I want to send multiple images in formdata format, so  far I  was sending single image in base65 format but here I have to send max 5 images as well in formdata format.

I am trying to solve this issue but I could not achieve  it .

My codes look like below .ts

```
    handleFiles= function (fileInput: Event) {

         if (fileInput.target['files'].length>1) {

            var files = Array.from(fileInput.target['files']);
    this.authService.sendMultipalImages(files).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);

    })

            }else{
                var files = Array.from(fileInput.target['files']);


                this.convertImageToBase64(files, []);
            }


                }


            convertImageToBase64(list, resultArray) {

              if(list.length){
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsBinaryString(list[0]);
                reader.onload = (evt: any) => {

                  const str = btoa(evt.target.result)
                  resultArray.push('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + str);
                  list.splice(0, 1);
                  console.log(list.length)
                  return this.convertImageToBase64(list, resultArray);
                };  
              } else {


                console.log(resultArray.length);

                    this.attached_image = resultArray[0];

                }
```

this is my service .ts file

```
sendMultipalImages = function(mImage){

      let formData: FormData = new FormData();

       formData.append('image', mImage);


        return this.http.post(this.api_url + 'uploadmultiple', formData, this.getUploadMulitpleImages()).map(res => res.json())
      }



header looks like this


getUploadMulitpleImages() {

            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
           headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
           headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.webToken);
          let option = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
       return option;
         }
```

Please how can I send multiple images to server.
Your help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: People will let you know that your code is formatted horribly :) And I think you mean base64??

Comment: What error do you receive when using your current method?

Comment: Sorry for that but  I do not want send in base64 format because it will increase size, so I want to send in like formdata (chunk)

Comment: I am able to send single image but for the multiple images whatever part of code I have written is correct or not , I am not sure .

Answer (score 0):

I found the Ans.
Just I removed these below thing from my header, did not make any changes in component file,

```
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.webToken);// this is optional
```

Service.ts

```
sendMultipalImages = function(mImage){
       debugger;
       var formData: FormData = new FormData();
       for (const file of mImage) {
        formData.append(file.name, file)

      }
    return this.http.post(this.api_url + 'uploadmultiple', formData, this.getUploadMulitpleImages()).map(res => res.json())
      }
```